# Как проверить заголовок и если он отличается, сделать перенаправление

Tags: php

Добрый день, StackOverflow!

Помогите пожалуйста с вопросом, делаю подобие облака с возможностью хранения файлов в персональных папках, я авторизуюсь под логином Дмитрий Афанасьев и ссылка к персональной папке имеет вид `http://programm.local/PersonalFiles/Дмитрий%20Афанасьев/`

Но если поменять на `http://programm.local/PersonalFiles/Александр%20Пушкин/`, то я вижу файлы пользователя Александра Пушкина, которые я видеть не должен.

Спасибо!

Comment: А причём тут заголовок ? думаю вы всё неправильно делаете. При авторизации проверяйте (установите куки или сессию) ID пользователя и показывайте его файлы. Зачем проверять по URL ?

Comment: @Arsen я проверяю авторизацию через сессию и сессионный ключ. Но это не помогает если изменить ссылку с браузера, так как сессионный ключ верный

Comment: Думаю при показе файлов вы просто что то некорректно проверяете, т.е не проверяете авторизирован ли пользователь

Comment: @Arsen если пользователь некорректно авторизован его выкидывает на страницу авторизации

Comment: я просто спинным мозгом чувствую  что вы при показе файлов просто проверяете авторизирован ли пользователь )))) но не проверяете какие папки показывать пользователю, т.е если авторизирован пользователь по ID 10 то при показе файлов вы должны показывать только для этого пользователя

Comment: @Arsen Да, проверяю только авторизацию:D Подскажите, как это реализовать?

Comment: Ничего сложного, при создании пользователя в таблице  храните USER ID + folder path и когда пользователь авторизировался, получите из базы его ссылку и при показе файлов всегда проверяйте SESSION USER ID + DATABASE USER ID + DATABASE USER FOLDER PATH

Comment: @Arsen Скорее всего это отвратительное решение но я сделал так


$a = parse_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
 if ($a['path'] != '/PersonalFiles/'.$_SESSION["Name"].'/index.php') {
  header('Location: /PersonalFiles/'.$_SESSION["Name"].'/index.php');
 }

Comment: ваш метод неверен )) я написал общую логику как надо сделать

Comment: @Arsen а если в http://programm.local/PersonalFiles/Дмитрий%20Афанасьев/ будут содержаться ещё несколько директорий, ну например http://programm.local/PersonalFiles/Дмитрий%20Афанасьев/[1,2,3,4,5,6], то как быть в этом случае? Записывать путь к каждой директории в mysql?

Comment: А какая разница какой путь будет до файлов ? весь путь храните в базе в виде одной строки и, когда пользователь авторизируется вы отправите по его пути которая в таблице сохранена

Comment: @Arsen Спасибо! Дошло:D